# Does Azure Pipelines have variables for multiple repo checkouts?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In my pipeline template, I am checking out code from 2 different repos:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: DeploymentRepo
    type: git
    name: MyProject/AWS.Deployment
...
  steps:
    - checkout: self
    - checkout: DeploymentRepo
```

Which creates 2 directories. One is named for the "self" repo and the other for the "DeploymentRepo". I used `$(Build.Repository.Name)` to reference the name of the "self" repo for the path. Is there a way to reference the other repo directory? I can also use `$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)`, but it only references the "self" repo. I want to reference the path to the "DeploymentRepo" using a variable. Do AZ pipelines support such a notion? I have read through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) several times, but I see nothing obvious.

Comment: Does this help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#repository-details ?

Comment: Why do you need to reference the repos through variables? Why can't you just append the repo name to `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` and access the repo that way, e.g. `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/DeploymentRepo`?

Alternatively you could always use task.setvariable to set a variable with the above value, but you'd need to explicitly add a task which did this, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#about-tasksetvariable

Comment: Ultimately it doesn't matter to use a variable or not. I just wanted to know if Azure Pipelines supported the concept of referencing the directory where source files are downloaded based on the repo they are downloaded from. Just feels wrong to hard code something if there's a variable that can tell me the same things. So if the repo name changes I don't have to go update code.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't such a variable. As suggested in the comments, using `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/DeploymentRepo` or `$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/DeploymentRepo` are the variables mostly used for this.

Answer (score 0):

When you checked multiple repos in the same jobs of a YAML pipeline, each repo generally will be checked out to the path "**`$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/<repo name>`**" by default.

1. For the self repo where the YAML is hosted, you can use the predefined variable "**`Build.Repository.Name`**" to get the repo name.
2. For each resource repos, you can use the [repository resource variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#variables-2) "**`resources.repositories.<Alias>.name`**" to get the repo name.

   **Note:** For repository resource variables, you cannot directly reference them on the pipeline tasks using the expression like as "**`$(resources.repositories.<Alias>.name)`**", you need to first map them as the pipeline variables, and then reference the pipeline variables.

See below example.

```yaml
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: DeploymentRepo
    type: git
    name: MyProject/AWS.Deployment

variables:
  DeploymentRepo.name: $[ resources.repositories.DeploymentRepo.name ]

...
  steps:
    - checkout: self
    - checkout: DeploymentRepo

    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Show Infor'
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          echo "Build.Repository.Name = $(Build.Repository.Name)"
          echo "DeploymentRepo.name = $(DeploymentRepo.name)"

# $(Build.Repository.Name) returns the name of the self repo.
# $(DeploymentRepo.name) returns the name of resource repo.
```

---

Comment: I'd like to know whether you have tried predefined repository resource variable "**`resources.repositories.<Alias>.name`**" shared in my above answer to get the name of repository resource. Is this working for you? @GetShifting